# How to dynamically fill datagrid without bindings?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Just subj. Can't find how to do that without databindings.

I'm trying to do that simply like that:

```
maingrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);

DataGrid listOfExercises = new DataGrid();

listOfExercises.ItemsSource = GetDayExercises(ref time);

Grid.SetRowSpan(listOfExercises, maingrid.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
Grid.SetColumn(listOfExercises, maingrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count - 1);

maingrid.Children.Add(listOfExercises);
```

GetDayExercises() returns int[]. I've got the next result:

[image: Program window]

Number of rows is the same as must be, but where are the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you miss `Binding`. Try this:

```
DataGridTextColumn col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
col1.Binding = new Binding();
dataGrid1.Columns.Add(col1);

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
```

It shows datagrid with numbers from 1 to 10